# The definition of graph in C

Tags: c

I set the definition of adjacency list node like this:

```
typedef struct node_type{  
int data;
struct node_type *link;
}node;
```

The definition of adjacency list:

```
typedef node *list;
```

The definition of graph:( A graph is an array of adjacency lists)

```
typedef struct graph_type{
int no_of_vertex;
list *array;
}graph;
```

Was it a correct definition anyway?

Comment: **Don't** `typedef` a pointer! This will eventually result in confusion.

Comment: This looks like a singly-linked list. Which I guess counts as a graph, but it's kind of degenerate.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. There is more than one way to define a graph in C (as with any language). Without knowing what your intent was, it's impossible to say whether you have succeeded or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your question but I'm assuming you were asking about  adjacency list representation of an undirected graph.

Trying to be as close as your original idea -

First you define a structure to represent an adjacency list node -

```
struct AdjListNode
{
    int dest;
    struct AdjListNode* next;
};
```

Then a structure to represent an adjacency list -

```
struct AdjList
{
    struct AdjListNode *head;  // pointer to head node of list
};
```

Then a structure to represent a graph. Here a graph is an array of adjacency lists. Size of array will be V (number of vertices in graph).

```
struct Graph
{
    int V;
    struct AdjList* array;
};
```

For better understanding of different graph representations there are number of useful resources that you can google. Here are few -

https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/graph-representation/a/representing-graphs

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/

Comment: Yes. U assumed correctly.. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

You either store a list of adjacencies and a list of nodes,

```
typedef struct node_type{  
   int data;
} node;

typedef struct adj_type {
   node * n1;
   node * n2;
} adj;

typedef struct graph_type{
   int n_nodes;
   int n_adjs;
   node ** node_list;
   adj ** adj_list;
}graph;
```

Or store a node with its adjacencies:

```
typedef struct node_type{  
   int data;
   int n_links;
   sturct node_type ** links;
} node;

typedef struct node_type{
   int n_nodes;
   node ** node_list;
}
```

If you use linked list containers to store the nodes/adjacencies instead of  pointer arrays you separate the graph logic from the memory allocation logic.